# Inserting rows into linear-indexed, collapsed matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

Say we have an `n`-dimensional logical array `P` describing whether certain positions in an n-space are "set" or "cleared" (with respect to some attribute), and these positions are also represented along the *rows* of a 2-dimensional floating-point matrix `Q`. The mapping of subscripts `P(a1,a2,...,an)` to linear indices `Q(idx,:)` is done in MATLAB's usual column-major ordering. However, only positions that are set (true) in `P` get to have a row in `Q`; which I gather is a poor man's way to achieve a sparse representation of data. (I must use this somewhat complicated P/Q data structure; that I cannot change.)

So far so good. However, once `P` and `Q` are constructed, I may want to set more entries in `P` and add corresponding rows to `Q`. That has to be done without breaking the mapping of n-positions between P and Q. A routine I've come up with to achieve that is:

```matlab
idxold=find(P);
P=P|deltaP; %deltaP only contains new positions we want to set; a sanity check with  any(P(:)&deltaP(:))  has been performed already
Q=[Q ; deltaQ]; %deltaQ contains new rows corresponding to the positions in deltaP

idxnew_ideal=find(P); %this is the order the rows of Q should be in
idxnew=[idxold ; idxnew_ideal(~ ismember(idxnew_ideal,idxold))]; %this is the order the rows of Q effectively are in at the moment

[~,rowidxs]=sort(idxnew); %order in which the rows of Q have to be reassembled
Q=Q(rowidxs,:);
```

Is there a more intelligent way to insert rows into `Q` at the proper locations?

**Edit (example data).** Typical inputs could be:

```matlab
P=zeros([3 3 2 2]);
P(1,1:3,2,1)=1;
ncolsQ=7;
Q=randi([-9 9],[sum(~~P(:)) ncolsQ]);

deltaP=zeros(size(P));
deltaP(2,2,1:2,1)=1;
deltaQ=randi([-9 9],[sum(~~deltaP(:)) ncolsQ]);
```

where `Q(1,:)` describes the n-position (1,1,2,1) and `deltaQ(2,:)` describes the n-position (2,2,2,1), for example.

Comment: No, I don't think there is, this is very smart. I just wonder if it's correct. So `deltaP` may change the indices like hell ... is that `ismember` really getting the new values of the old indices?

Comment: Oops I'm sorry, that was meant to be a negation of ismember(). The idea there is to extract the linear indices of the newly added entries. Let me fix that...

Comment: ... done :) As for `deltaP`, it only specifies additional n-positions to be set; this is an insertion-only routine, so the indices cannot change quite arbitrarily. (Although the problem could be generalized to include clearing entries in `P` / dropping rows from `Q`). But indeed, the thing with this approach is that while it rationally _looks_ correct, it's not very intuitive to me...

Comment: I was under impression that `deltaP` will push old indices to new values, but now I see - the old indices remain the same but new indices might get "activated"  between them, so it seems OK

Comment: Yes, that's right! The old data remain constant, only new stuff is added in between.

Comment: I'm testing it on a toy example and I have just one question: suppose `find(P)` is `[1, 4, 8]`. What's the shape of `Q`? Does it have 8 rows with rows 2, 3, 5 and 7 zero?

Comment: Nice to see a well-written question here every once in a while :-) Your approach looks good to me. I was thinking about skipping the final sorting, but now I see it's necessary. Unless you replace `P` by a numerical vector, which could then be kept unsorted (but would have variable size)

Comment: @kikon: I've added example inputs to make things clearer. Q has as many rows as P has true-valued entries, in short.

Comment: @LuisMendo: Thanks for your comment :) As for getting rid of P, unfortunately I can't do that because this P/Q structure is required by some complicated third-party code.

Comment: Thanks to the two of you for your remarks! :relieved:

Comment: I checked with my toy example and I get it clear that it's okay; I would have inserted `deltaQ` in `Q` row by row but that were much uglier and inefficient. I don't think there's any way that you could improve it.

Comment: `deltaQ` can be computed by `deltaP` so the following code may be more readable than yours: `sub = cell(1, ndims(P));P = P | deltaP;[sub{:}] = ind2sub(size(P), find(P));Q = [sub{:}];`

Comment: @rahnema1: Hmm I'm not sure I can see in which way that approach would be advantageous here, but it's sure an interesting idea to deal the outputs of `ind2sub` to entries of a cell array. Thanks, that might come in handy sometime (:

Comment: It depends on your definition of `intelligent`.

Comment: @rahnema1: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude. I just couldn't see how having an auxiliary matrix `[sub{:}]` of subscripts describing the n-positions affects the overall problem of appending and then reordering rows. Would you care to elaborate on your concept?

Comment: Imagine a person that want to reason about the code. Your code is cluttered with functions `sort` and `ismember` that makes difficult reading and reasoning.  You want to convert a logical matrix to a matrix of indices. What I proposed I think is more readable and it just is using `ind2sub`.

Comment: Oops! you are right. Reading your example `deltaQ` contains data other than indices into `P`.

Comment: @rahnema1: I think you missed the point of the question in the original post. `Q` is not matrix of indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without using `sort` and `ismember`:

```
idx = zeros(numel(P), 1);

idxold = find(P);
P = P | deltaP; 
Q = [Q ; deltaQ]; 
idx(P) = 1:size(Q, 1);
Q([idx(idxold); idx(find(deltaP))], :) = Q;
```

The solution requires an index vector `idx` to be preallocated.

Comment: Nice! Doing the complicated addressing in the left-hand side was a wise move!